# Como manipular um vetor de structs em uma função externa? Segue exemplo

Tags: c, funções, ponteiro, struct

Estou com dúvida em uma questão. Segue o enunciado:

Implementar um sistema para controle de biblioteca com funções para cadastrar, consultar, alterar e remover livros.

Os atributos de um livro são:

- Nome (Título do livro, com espaços)
- Autor (Nome completo com espaços)
- ISBN (Número de 11 dígitos)
- Volume (Número romano)
- Data (Data)
- Editora (Texto com espaço)
- Número de Páginas (Número inteiro)

E a struct que criei para este problema foi essa :

```
struct informacoes
{
    char nome[100];
    char autor[100];
    long long int isbn;
    char volume[10];
    int data;
    char editora[100];
    int paginas;
};
```

Gostaria de saber como passar um vetor desta struct como parâmetro de uma função, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tem um código que está fazendo pra gente ver onde você está tendo dificuldade?

Comment: Tenho sim, mas, este problema foi resolvido, a dúvida que me resta é sobre a questão das strings, não consigo ler as strings do função cadastro do código que passarei a seguir

Comment: @LuizCampos então sua dúvida agora é outra? Outra dúvida, melhor outra pergunta, não?

Comment: É verdade, postarei uma outra pergunta

Answer (score 1):

O vetor é passado como se fosse um vetor de outro tipo normal como `int` por exemplo. Assim:

```
void func(struct informacoes arr[]){
     //fazer algo com o array de informações
}

int main(){
     struct informacoes arr[10];

     func(arr); //chamando so com o nome do array
     return 0;
}
```

Com ponteiros passaria a ser:

```
void func(struct informacoes *arr){
     //fazer algo com o array de informações
}

int main(){
     struct informacoes *arr = malloc(sizeof(struct informacoes)*10);

     func(arr); //chamando so com o nome do ponteiro
     return 0;
}
```

É importante de mencionar que passando o vetor normal ou o ponteiro é na verdade a mesma coisa. A notação de vetor é apenas uma forma mais fácil para manipularmos o array, o compilador depois trata tudo como ponteiros.

Comment: Muito obrigado, gostaria de saber se também posso fazer isso usando um ponteiro, se sim, como?

Comment: Muito obrigado!